# How to actually make menu walker alive on admin interface?

Tags: menus, walker

I seen many articles about navigation menu walking:

http://hookr.io/4.5.2/files/wp-admin-includes-class-walker-nav-menu-edit/

[How to add a custom field in the advanced menu properties?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33342/how-to-add-a-custom-field-in-the-advanced-menu-properties)

the problem is, its just a definition. How to actually make it alive?

Answer (score 3):

You use the walker in your theme, wherever you call your nav menu.

So for example, if you currently have a "topnav" menu in your theme, like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'topnav');
```

and your custom walker is called "myCustomWalker", you would update the `wp_nav_menu` call like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu'   => 'topnav', 
        'walker' => new myCustomWalker()
    ) 
);
```

Just make sure to work in a child theme, so that when your theme updates, your call to the new walker (and the walker itself) are not lost.

Comment: yea, thats right, but I cant see this method call at all

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Have you added the walker to your theme and tried to call it - and it's not outputting correctly?

Comment: I was browsing for this method and its not used anywhere.

Comment: because Im using "ultimatum" theme

Comment: Not all themes use custom walkers. They're not always necessary, it just depends on what HTML you need from your nav_menus. If you want to start using one, create a child theme and use the walker there.